# Chrome not logging to console on scroll event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I have a simple scroll event listener:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',
  function()
  {
    //alert('test');
    console.log('test');
  }
);
```

I use Chrome and the result is not logged to the Console. The console just stays empty.
If I however uncomment the alert, I can see that the event is being executed when I scroll.

I do not understand why there is no output to the console?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Its working fine on my Chrome v 41....
logging when i scroll the page

Comment: Works fine for me on chrome win 8.

Comment: That's very strange. Maybe there is something on the page that prevents logging? I use for example desandro's masonry. And the YUI is present as well.

Comment: Any chance you have some code redefining console.log somewhere? Sometimes this is done to keep calls to it from breaking in older IE versions...